# Objects in JSON array - Can't get multidimenson arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON file with a String like this:

```
[{"Ean":"","Barcode":"010258100139","Bezeichnung":"Alia","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":129.90,"Vk":129.90}]
```

with PHP I try to get it into arrays so I can get the data:

```
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile);
$jsonarray = json_decode(json_encode($jsonarray), true);
var_dump( $jsonarray );
```

What I get is following:

```
array (size=3)
   0 => 
   array (size=8)
     'Ean' => string '' (length=0)
     'Barcode' => string '010258100139' (length=12)
     'Bezeichnung' => string 'Alia' (length=4)
     'Bestaende' => 
         array (size=1)
            0 => 
              array (size=5)
                  ...
     'Bestand' => int 1
     'Dispo' => int 0
     'Uvp' => float 129.9
     'Vk' => float 129.9
```

And thats it! I try many examples from here wit nested objects.
If I try to get data like

```
echo $jsonarray[0]['Barcode'];
```

I get my Barcode String without problems. But the data in "array (size=5)" I can't access.
I try many things like nested foreach loops, functions from here like "object_to_array", "json_encode2" and so on.

Can anybody give me a tip how I can access it? I Try to get ""Menge":1".

Thanks in advance.
Tyv

Comment: `echo $jsonarray['0']['Bestaende']['0']['Menge']; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only need one `json_decode`, like so:

```
$data = '[{"Ean":"","Barcode":"010258100139","Bezeichnung":"Alia","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":129.90,"Vk":129.90}]';

$jsonarray = json_decode($data,true);
```

When you print it out, you get:

```
print_r($jsonarray);// I use print_r as its output looks more like how you use it

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Ean] => 
            [Barcode] => 010258100139
            [Bezeichnung] => Alia
            [Bestaende] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Filiale] => 1
                            [FilialeBez] => Laden
                            [Menge] => 1
                            [Gln] => 
                            [Dispo] => 0
                        )
                )
            [Bestand] => 1
            [Dispo] => 0
            [Uvp] => 129.9
            [Vk] => 129.9
        )
)
```

So from there, you can see how you can get at certain points of data. For example you wanted Bestaende's first data array, so you would grab it as:

```
$jsonarray['0']['Bestaende']['0']; // for the whole group
$jsonarray['0']['Bestaende']['0']['Menge']; // for specific items
```

If you have multiple groups under Bestaende, then you could loop them doing what you need to do with each:

```
foreach($jsonarray['0']['Bestaende'] as $idx => $Bestaende) {
    $Bestaende['Menge']; // to use that specific data of that group this loop
}
```