# Array in Array in Array - Cant get data from JSON String

Tags: php, arrays, json

Original Post: [Objects in Arrays...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288165/objects-in-json-array-cant-get-multidimenson-arrays)

The data I provided was only one line. I have many lines of the same with different "Bestaende" and "Menge":

```
[{"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770148","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90},      
 {"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770149","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90},
 {"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770151","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90},
 {"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770152","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90}]
```

The `foreach` you describe I understand, but it doesn't work as expected .

```
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile,true);
echo 'Array 0 Menge: '.$jsonarray['0']['Bestaende']['0']['Menge'].'<br>'; 
echo 'Array 1 Menge: '.$jsonarray['1']['Bestaende']['0']['Menge'].'<br>'; 
echo 'Array 2 Menge: '.$jsonarray['2']['Bestaende']['0']['Menge'].'<br>'; 
echo 'Array 3 Menge: '.$jsonarray['3']['Bestaende']['0']['Menge'].'<br>';
```

brings out

```
Array 0 Menge: 1
Array 1 Menge: 1
Array 2 Menge: 1
Array 3 Menge: 1
```

Okay. But when I try to `foreach` it (because I have a list of base data), the output is only one row. I get only one entry "1". Nothing more.

```
$x=0;
foreach($jsonarray[$x]['Bestaende'] as $idx => $Bestaende) {
   echo 'Print Menge: ';
   print_r($Bestaende['Menge']); 
 $x++;
}
```

So I try to loop over the Array to get the data. The Result is:

```
Array ( [Filiale] => 1 [FilialeBez] => Laden [Menge] => 1 [Gln] => [Dispo] => 0 )
Print Menge: 1
```

I have a problem with the array in array in array ... Is there a better way to get the data I want?

Or is my `foreach` loop wrong?

Comment: Yes, your foreach is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
foreach($jsonarray as $k=>$alldata) 
{
   foreach($alldata["Bestaende"] as $idx => $Bestaende) 
   {
       echo '<pre>';
       echo 'Print Menge: '.$Bestaende['Menge'];
       echo '</pre>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop only over `$jsonarray[0]['Bestaende']` which only contains one item. You should loop over `$jsonarray` and from there dive in deeper.

```
foreach($jsonarray as $item) {
    echo 'Print Menge: ';
    print_r($item['Bestaende']['0']['Menge']); 
    // or even dive in deeper
    foreach ($item['Bestaende'] as $bestaende) {
        // .. $bestaende['Menge'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code..
$j = '[{"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770148","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90},      
 {"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770149","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90},
 {"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770151","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90},
 {"Ean":"","Barcode":"010241770152","Bezeichnung":"Richard 1516","Bestaende":[{"Filiale":1,"FilialeBez":"Laden","Menge":1,"Gln":null,"Dispo":0}],"Bestand":1,"Dispo":0,"Uvp":269.90,"Vk":269.90}]';

$a = json_decode($j,true);

foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($value['Bestaende'])){
        foreach($value['Bestaende'] as $k=>$v){
             echo 'Print Menge: '.(!empty($v['Menge']) ? $v['Menge'] : '').'</br>';
        }
    }
}
```